# How to Nest Divs

Tags: html

So, what I am trying to do, is put a div inside a div. The text editor reads the second div's end as the first one's.

This kind of stumped me, so I haven't really tried anything else

```
 <div id="navbar">

</div>
<div id="else">
<div>
</div>
<div id="project1">

</div>
</div>
```

The last div should go with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div id="navbar">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="innerOne">

    </div>

    <div id="innerTwo">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Be sure to make good use of indenting and spacing if you want to make things easier on yourself!

If you notice in your code when you declare the first div you immediately close it again and start a new one, every other div wants to be nested inside it.

```
 <div id="navbar">
 A Div on it's own
</div>
<div id="else">
A new div on the same 'level' as the last
<div>
      a Child of the else div
</div>
<div id="project1">
    second Child of the else div
</div>
  end of else
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. Ya, I usually indent my code, but since it got on here, it got messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Figuring the nesting is easier when you:

1. Indent the code, and
2. Add comments to track the (matching) closing tags

`<div id='navbar'>` // open navbar
    `<div id='else'>`
    `</div>` //end else
    `<div id='project1'>`
    `</div>` //end project1
`</div>` //end navbar

(my code block thing is being buggy, but I hope you understand what I was saying...)

Answer (score 0):

In `HTML` after most **opening tag** should come the content and then the `closing tag`
in your case ...

There are **self-closing tags** also, which don't need a closing one for example: `<img src="">`

Your code is wrong, because after the `<div id="else">` you have another `div` opening tag, but there should be a closing tag before it, like this:

```
<div id="navbar">
</div>
<div id="else">
</div>
<div id="project1">
</div>
```

Nesting divs should look like this:

```
<div id="navbar></div>
<div id="else">
    <div id="project1"></div>
</div>
```